# Custom legend of several lines with two markers for the same text

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like perform the type of legend shown in the figure [image].

That figure I did with some tricks just to represent what I really want so it does not show well the color of the pink markers in the legend.

In the figure the circles represent the same parameter but for two different models; the same is true for the triangular and square markers. I want to place the two circular markers referring to the same parameter in the first line of the legend, and analogously for the two other markers on the lines below this one. Thank you.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q1 = [100.0, 60.0, 200.0, 300.0]
NO1 = [0.35799999999999998, 0.33100000000000002, 0.22900000000000001,     0.17799999999999999]
No1 = [0.34599999999999997, 0.29899999999999999, 0.20699999999999999, 0.14999999999999999]
Nb1 = [0.46600000000000003, 0.45600000000000002, 0.27800000000000002, 0.24399999999999999]

q2 = [60.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0]
NO2 = [0.44700000000000001, 0.29199999999999998, 0.28299999999999997, 0.253]
No2 = [0.38900000000000001, 0.28499999999999998, 0.311, 0.251]
Nb2 = [0.44, 0.34899999999999998, 0.45900000000000002, 0.39400000000000002]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,3))

ax.plot(q1, NO1, marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1, color = 'gray', linestyle = '', markersize = 8, label = '$N$ in parameter a')
ax.plot(q2, NO2, marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1, color = 'palevioletred', linestyle = '', markersize = 8)#, label = '$N$ in parameter a')
ax.plot(q1, No1, marker = '^', markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1, color = 'gray', linestyle = '', markersize = 8, label = '$N$ in parameter b')
ax.plot(q2, No2, marker = '^', markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1, color = 'palevioletred', linestyle = '', markersize = 8)#, label = '$N$ in parameter b')  
ax.plot(q1, Nb1, marker = 's', markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1, color = 'gray', linestyle = '', markersize = 8, label = '$N$ in parameter c') 
ax.plot(q2, Nb2, marker = 's', markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1, color = 'palevioletred', linestyle = '', markersize = 8)#, label = '$N$ in parameter c')
#plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.945, 1))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('$N$')
plt.xticks([60, 100, 200, 300])
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_params(direction = 'in', bottom = True, top = True, left = True, right = True, which = 'major')    
plt.tick_params(direction = 'in', bottom = False, top = False, left = True, right = True, which = 'minor')
```

Comment: It's sure possible, but could you provide a test case (i.e. a code one can work with). Are there only ever two different colors involved?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, only two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a `HandlerTuple` handler and provide tuples of the artists to show in each row as handles to the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.legend_handler

q1 = [100.0, 60.0, 200.0, 300.0]
NO1 = [0.358, 0.331, 0.229, 0.178]
No1 = [0.346, 0.299, 0.207, 0.15]
Nb1 = [0.466, 0.456, 0.278, 0.244]

q2 = [60.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0]
NO2 = [0.447, 0.292, 0.283, 0.253]
No2 = [0.389, 0.285, 0.311, 0.251]
Nb2 = [0.44, 0.349, 0.459, 0.394]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,3))

prop = dict(markerfacecolor = 'none', markeredgewidth = 1,
            linestyle = '', markersize = 8,)
l1, = ax.plot(q1, NO1, marker = 'o', color = 'gray', label = '$N$ in parameter a', **prop)
l2, = ax.plot(q2, NO2, marker = 'o', color = 'palevioletred', **prop)
l3, = ax.plot(q1, No1, marker = '^', color = 'gray', label = '$N$ in parameter b', **prop)
l4, = ax.plot(q2, No2, marker = '^', color = 'palevioletred', **prop)
l5, = ax.plot(q1, Nb1, marker = 's', color = 'gray', label = '$N$ in parameter c', **prop) 
l6, = ax.plot(q2, Nb2, marker = 's', color = 'palevioletred', **prop)


handles = [(l1,l2), (l3,l4), (l5,l6)]
_, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(handles = handles, labels=labels, loc='upper right', 
          handler_map = {tuple: matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple(None)})

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('$N$')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yesterday I thought your code worked. Did you make any changes? Today I have this error when compiling. 

"   handler_map = {tuple: matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple(None)})
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
"

Would you please tell me what the error is?

Comment: I did not change anything (you would see if the answer got edited similar to how you see that you edited your question 16 hours ago). Did you run this in two different versions of matplotlib or python? Does it work when using `HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)`?

Comment: It also gives error:
"    HandlerBase.__init__(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ndivide'
"

Comment: What does `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` give you?

Comment: It gives: 2.0.0

Comment: Ok. Two options: Do you want me to try and find a solution which works with 2.0, or are you able to update your matplotlib version?

Comment: Indeed the problem was the version of matplotlib. Thank you very much.