# Adding a legend entry with two curves on same entry, python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to have a legend like the one appearing on the plot below: As you can see the legend entry shows the red line and the blue line on the same entry.

PD: In my case, the red line is always the same curve, a horizontal straight line.

[image: Example graph]
How can I do this? I have tried with the examples in [this guide](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/legend_guide.html), but they do not apply to my case, since I do not find a "handlebox artist" which applies to my case.

**Edit**: I have tried to apply @Mr.T answer, but in my case I am plotting the blue plot as a bar plot in matplotlib, and I get the following error `AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute '_transform'`.

What I am doing is

```
blue_bars = axes[i].bar(bins[:-1], Wi, width = binsize, label = label_W)
red_line = axes[i].hlines(0, tstart, tstop, color='red', linewidth = 0.8)
axes[i].legend([red_line, blue_bars], labels = label_W,
            handler_map={blue_bars: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=5)},
            loc='upper right')
```

Note that I am creating several subplots in the same axes object, within a for loop that iterates over the variable `i`. This works with no problem.

Comment: Currently, you don't ask a question. Have you tried to implement any of the methods suggested in the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#legend-handlers)?

Comment: None of those methods apply to my case. I have tried to use the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478077/how-to-make-two-markers-share-the-same-label-in-the-legend-using-matplotlib), but it does not apply exactly to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [linked examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists), we can construct a legend entry from scratch as you did not tell us how you plot the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
red_hline = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="red")
blue_uptick = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="blue", lw=0, marker=2, markersize=5)
orange_downtick = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="orange", lw=0, marker=3, markersize=5)

ax.legend(handles=[(red_hline, blue_uptick), (red_hline, orange_downtick)], 
          labels=["the ups", "and the downs"], 
          handler_map={blue_uptick: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=5), orange_downtick: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=3)})

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: This does not work in my case, (I think) since my blue lines are plotted with a Bar Plot. I am using [plt.Bar](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) for this and I get the error `AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute '_transform'.

Comment: As this legend is constructed from scratch without any input from the artists plotted in this axis object, I do not know why you would need the bar containers.

Comment: Well, the bar plot is input in the legend handler_map (in your example is `blue_uptick: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=5)`), but in my case blue_uptick is built with a bar plot (see my update in the question)

Comment: This is understood. But I don't know why you want to use the bar rectangle patch to generate your legend - it will be more complicated and does not look much different. But you will have your reasons, so maybe someone else will provide what you want.